# Restrict and filter entries in Global Address List object to reduce loop run time

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking to find entries in the Global Address List using VBA. I'm looking for distribution lists that start with a specific prefix.

The GAL contain thousand of entries. A regular loop takes ages. I ran across the .Restrict and .Filter methods, but I couldn't find a way to make them work.

I am running Office version 2302 on Windows 11.

Comment: Get the GAL into a VBA array then use the vba array filter method to select out names with the desired prefix.

Comment: How do I get the GAL into a VBA array? The GAL is more than 500,000 entries, would that work fine?

Comment: I don't know, it was just a suggestion.  But at least I can google.  https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/How-to-retrieve-of-all-email-addresses-that-might-belong-to-a/m-p/1532453#M89340 to find things that might be worth pursuing.

Comment: The code contained in this post doesn't really help, because it loops through all the entries of the GAL, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid (because the entire loop takes too much time) by means of the .Find or .Restrict methods.

Comment: But at least I googled.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting to Google, really a good idea, it would have never crossed my mind to use Google (nor ChatGPT...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that in the Outlook Object Model - you can loop through all GAL entries, but that will be too slow and will fail for large GAL containers (as you have noticed).

In Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), you can create a`PR_ANR` restriction to get all matches in a given address book container - that is what Outlook uses to show the list of ambiguous entries.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can use `RDOSession.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveNameEx` which returns a list of matches:

```
  set rSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  rSession.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set AdrrEntries = rSession.AddressBook.GAL.ResolveNameEx("joe")
  Debug.Print AdrrEntries.Count & " names were returned by ResolveNameEx:"
  Debug.Print "------------"
  for each AE in AdrrEntries
    Debug.Print AE.Name
  next
  Debug.Print "------------"
```